# Getting error while using HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri(location) in Django

Tags: python, django

My code:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest

admin_subject = "New question added"
admin_message = "A new question has been successfully added. Please review and approve it."
location = reverse("admin:appname_question_change", args=(new_question.pk,))
url = HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri(location)
admin_html_message = "<h3>%s</h3>\
                        <p>%s</p>\
                        <a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (admin_subject, admin_message, url, url)
mail_admins(admin_subject, admin_message, fail_silently=False, connection=None, html_message=admin_html_message)
```

I am getting this error:

```
unbound method build_absolute_uri() must be called with HttpRequest instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

I have tried much but don't know what is causing this error.
I want absolute uri to be sent in email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the error you are getting is very definitive. `build_absolute_uri` is an instance method so should be called by an  `HttpRequest` instance.

```
>>> from django.http import HttpRequest

>>> request = HttpRequest()
>>> location = reverse("admin:appname_question_change", args=(new_question.pk,))
>>> url = request.build_absolute_uri(location)
```